# How does while loop work without a condition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, splice

I understand that it's removing the first 3 elements of the `array` and adding them to the new array. But how does the function continue to add ensuing chunks of the array to the new array variable?

How does the `while` loop work without proper conditions?

How does it work in collaboration with `splice()` here?

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size){
  let newArr = [];
  while(arr.length){
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size))
  }
  return newArr;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Comment: Eventually `arr.length` will be zero, which will evaluate to false.

Comment: How is it decrementing without a decrementing variable?

Comment: The `splice` command removes 2 elements from the array. So `length` gets smaller each time until it is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is `while(arr.length)`. The while loop will run while that condition is **truthy**. In JavaScript every condition is truthy unless it is one of the following:

> false
>
> 0 (zero)
>
> '' or "" (empty string)
>
> null
>
> undefined
>
> NaN (e.g. the result of 1/0)

In your case the `while` loop will run while the array has elements in it (`arr.length` is greater than zero), because if the `arr.length` is zero the while loop will stop executing.

`arr.splice` on the other hand is removing one element from `arr` every time it is executed (it is changing the `arr` length). So when there are no elements left in the `arr` (because `arr.splice` removed them all) the `while` loop will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions in js are either "truthy" or "falsy", for numbers everything except 0 is "truthy", 0 is "falsy". That means that the loop runs until the array is empty, its length 0 and therefore falsy.

```
 if(0) alert("never");
 if(1) alert("always");
 let i = 3;
 while(i) console.log(i--);
```

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is gonna keep going until the original array is empty. Splice will remove the selected elements from the original array and while will continue until the last elements are removed.

Also, as the elements are removed from the original array, they are being pushed (added) to the new array