# Can someone explain me this "while" loop? (the repetitions and the variable)

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm studying loops and I'm trying to understand this while loop:

```
var contador = 2;
var na = "na";
while(contador)
{
    na += na;
    contador -= 1;
}
console.log(na + " Freddy ")
```

I know the result of this is "nananana Freddy", but I don't understand why.

After the first iteration "na" would have another "na", so it would be "nana".
And, afer that first iteration, "contador" would be 1, right? (contador = 2-1). So why does it continue adding "na"?

EDIT: I understood now why it continues iterating until contador is equal to 0. But i still don't understand the "na" part.
why is "nana" after iteration 1 and "nananana" after iteration 2?

i would think after 2 iterations na is equal to "nanana". cause doesn't "na += na" means that it adds one "na" in each iteration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the while loop stop when condition check variable becomes 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974993/why-does-the-while-loop-stop-when-condition-check-variable-becomes-0) - it stops when it hits 0 so first iteration doubles na to nana, 2nd and final iteration doubles nana to nananana. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558602/how-does-while-loop-work-without-a-condition or one of the many other duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That while will be executed every time `contador` is `true` [it doesn't check if `contador` is still "2" but if javascript considers the value of `contador` [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy))]. In this case it will be executed two times, since "2" (first loop) and "1" (second loop) is equal to `true` but "0" isn't.

Now, one thing you can notice is that in line 5 (the line posted below this sentence) you are incrementing the value of the variable `contador` itself and not the string "na".

```
    na += na; # After the equal sign is the variable name instead of a string
```

Which means that the loop result will be:

```
# First loop
# contador = 2
# var na = "na";
while(2)
{
    na += na; # It will be "na" plus "na"
    contador -= 1;


    console.log(na + " Freddy ")
    # Prints "nana Freddy "
}



# Second loop
# contador = 1
# var na = "nana";
while(1)
{
    na += na; # It will be "nana" plus "nana"
    contador -= 1;


    console.log(na + " Freddy ")
    # Prints "nananana Freddy "
}
```

After those two loops `contador` becomes 0, which makes it not run again.

So basically line 5 is always duplicating the content of the variable `na`.

If you still have doubts, I recommend changing the name of the variable `na`. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: oooh, ok i had no idea about the true/false thing. there is still 1 thing i don't get..
why in the second loop is : 
"na += na" equal to "nana+nana"?  why is that not "nana + na"?

Comment: @danistor_m That happens because you are incrementing the whole value of the variable "na" instead of the string "na".
So, imagine that "na" is equal to "test_" (which means that in the beginning of the first loop it will be "test_"). After the first loop runs, it will be "test_test_" and after the second loop runs it will be "test_test_test_test_".
This means that if you wanted to make it "nana + na", then you would need to change the line 5 to:
na += "na";

Answer (score 4):

It continues because in JavaScript 0 is considered false all the other positive numbers to be true.

After the first iteration the string is "nana" and contador is 1.

Then in the next iteration na is already "nana" so na+=na means ''nananana"

Comment: oh i didn't know the true/false bit. can you explain me one more thing? why would the second iteration give  4 na and not 3?   i took "na+=na" as "add 1 na"

Comment: na+=na here na is already "nana" so na+=na means "nana"+="nana" which translates to "nananana"

Answer (score 3):

`while(contador)` will loop as long as `contador` is non-zero. It won't stop until `contador` reaches `0`.

After the first loop you are correct that `na === "nana"` and `contador === 1`. That's not zero, so it iterates again, resulting in `na === "nananana"` and `contador === 0`. That's when the loop stops.